# How to draw three-phase transformers like the one in the picture?

Tags: diagrams, circuitikz, engineering

How to draw three-phase transformers like the one in the picture?

[image]

I managed at most to make this code, which produces:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article} 
    
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{gensymb}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}% default line thickness
        \draw 
        [ultra thick] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \draw (0,0) to[short](4,0)
        (4,0) node[americaninductorshape, anchor=midtap, rotate=-90](L1){}
        ++(0.5,0) 
        node[americaninductorshape, rotate=90](L2){} (L2.midtap)
        to[short] (5.5,0);
        \draw [ultra thick] (5.5,-1) -- (5.5,1);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have any specific packages in mind? If yes, it would be nice if you provided some code where you show what you tried so far.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{inductors/coils=2}
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,-1) -- (0,1) 
      node[draw,thin,circle,above=0.5ex, pos=1] {\textbf{1}};% you could add some [xshift] if desired
    \draw (0,0) to[short](4,0)
    (4,0) node[americaninductorshape, anchor=midtap, rotate=-90](L1){}
    ++(0.6,0) 
    node[americaninductorshape, rotate=90](L2){} (L2.midtap)
    to[short] (5.5,0);
    \draw [ultra thick] (5.5,-1) -- (5.5,1)
      node[draw,thin,circle,above=0.5ex, pos=1] {\textbf{2}};% reduce [inner sep] to make circle smaller
    \node[above, font=\large] at (L1.west) {1};
    \node[above, font=\large] at (L2.east) {1};
    \node[above, font=\large] at ($(L1.west)!0.5!(L2.east)$) {:};
    \node[below, font=\large] at ($(L1.east)!0.5!(L2.west)$) {$\textbf{\textsf{T}}_1$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: MIssing circle numbers 1 and 2, +1

Comment: @Sebastiano - Fixed now.